# Check instance of anonymous object

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

If I create an anonymous class in Kotlin like this:

```
if(condition) {
  object: Foo() {
    fun bar() {  
    // code
   }  
 }  
} else {
  Foo()
}
```

Is there a way to check in the code that the current instance has is the `object` class and hence I can call `bar()` which does not exist in `Foo`?

Comment: this looks like a code smell, shouldn't you return `lambda` here?

Comment: @m.antkowicz: the original code returns a class Foo that I want to override. How would the `lambda` help the situation here?

Comment: if you're interested in a `bar` method it may mean that not whole `Foo` is being used just some specific method from it - then you could return this as a lambda

Comment: anyway by extending `Foo` you're no longer returning `Foo` from this part of code so you need to refactor it

Comment: @m.antkowicz: So if I need to check the instanceOf what would I be checking?

Comment: @m.antkowicz: I do need `Foo` too so lambda is not of use here

Comment: you cannot check with any *instanceOf/is* because the type is being lost after return - take a look at the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) - this part: `If you use an anonymous object as a return type of a public function or the type of a public property, the actual type of that function or property will be the declared supertype of the anonymous object, or Any if you didn't declare any supertype.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That object expression is [creating an anonymous class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions), like m.antkowicz has pointed out:

> Note that anonymous objects can be used as types only in local and private declarations. If you use an anonymous object as a return type of a public function or the type of a public property, the actual type of that function or property will be the declared supertype of the anonymous object, or Any if you didn't declare any supertype. Members added in the anonymous object will not be accessible.

That means your `if` expression is returning a local type which *is* known to contain `bar()`, but once it leaves that scope it will be declared as the supertype you used - it will be a `Foo` which does not contain a `bar()` method.

So, you need to use a supertype that *does* contain that member - you can use an interface to this, just like when you define a (non-anonymous) class:

```
interface Bar {
    fun bar()
}

object : Foo(), Bar {
    override fun bar() {...}
}
```

then you can use `is Foo` and `is Bar` to check which types the object has.

If you want to arbitrarily add functions to objects outside of the type system, and have other code able to know those functions are there, you're probably looking at doing [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html)